# How to request fresh token using Oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, token

Am requesting access token from [ExactOnline API](https://developers.exactonline.com/#OAuth_Tutorial.html%3FTocPath%3DAuthentication%7C_____2) using `refresh token` as their documentation states but I all get is `Bad Request` am using [Oauth2](https://rubygems.org/gems/oauth2) to send POST request to there API. I have tried googling but none of the examples given is helpful.

**This is what i have so far.**

```
     def to_params
      {
         'refresh_token' => refresh_token,
          'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
          'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
          'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
      }
  end

  def request_token_from_exact
    #Request a new token if the given token is expired.
    client = OAuth2::Client.new(self.to_params['client_id'], self.to_params['client_secret'], site: 'https://start.exactonline.nl')
    access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, self.to_params['fresh_token'])
    @response = access_token.post('/api/oauth2/token')
    puts "Response Status: "+@response.status
  end
```

How can i use Oauth2 to get a new token. Or is their any way I can do it to get a new token if the given one has expired.

*Your response will be appreciated.*

Comment: You can use refresh token only once to get new access token. Hope you are not using any invalid refresh token

Comment: Yes am using refresh token to get a new token. But it returns `Bad  Request`

Answer (score 1):

In your code replace
`self.to_params['fresh_token']` with `self.to_params['refresh_token']` here

Comment: That solved my issue of `Bad Request` but still am influencing a bigger issue than the first `Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.`

Comment: You are getting unauthorized error because you might be trying to use same refresh token to get the new access token. Once you use refresh token it can not be used again. Try to get access token first using normal way and then try that refresh token to get new access token